# CKeditor - How to bind a keystroke to apply <code> tag to selected text

Tags: ckeditor

I have bound almost all the keystrokes I need for CKEditor, save for `<code>`. How can  bind a keystroke for that HTML tag?

```
config.keystrokes = [
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 32 /*space*/, 'removeFormat' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 56 /*8*/, 'bulletedlist' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 56 /*8*/, 'bulletedListStyle' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 77 /*M*/, 'indent' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 77 /*M*/, 'outdent' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 188 /*COMMA*/, 'subscript' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 190 /*PERIOD*/, 'superscript' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 73 /*I*/, 'image' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 75 /*K*/, 'link' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 75 /*K*/, 'unlink' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 70 /*F*/, 'find' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 88 /*X*/, 'maximize' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 113 /*F2*/, 'preview' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 80 /*P*/, 'print' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 72 /*H*/, 'replace' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 83 /*S*/, 'scaytcheck' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 66 /*B*/, 'showblocks' ],

    // [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 90 /*Z*/, 'source' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 121 /*F10*/, 'toolbarFocus' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 122 /*F11*/, 'elementsPathFocus' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 121 /*F10*/, 'contextMenu' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 90 /*Z*/, 'undo' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 89 /*Y*/, 'redo' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 90 /*Z*/, 'redo' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 76 /*L*/, 'link' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 66 /*B*/, 'bold' ],
    //[ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + CKEDITOR.ALT + 68 /*D*/, 'code' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 73 /*I*/, 'italic' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 85 /*U*/, 'underline' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 109 /*-*/, 'toolbarCollapse' ]
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that you cannot have just by editing the config. Go ahead with the following code (+[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gz6U5/)):

```
var codeStyle = new CKEDITOR.style( {
        element: 'code'
    } );

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
            // Register a new command that applies the style.
            this.addCommand( 'codeCommand', new CKEDITOR.styleCommand( codeStyle ) );            

            // Bind the command to CTRL+SHIFT+L.
            this.setKeystroke( CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 76, 'codeCommand' );
        }
    }
} );
```

Also see docs for: [`editor.addCommand`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-addCommand), [`editor.setKeystroke`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setKeystroke) and [`CKEDITOR.styleCommand`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.styleCommand).